# I missed Tahajud time by 10 minutes but still performed the prayer before offering Fajr prayer. Will my Tahajud prayer be accepted?

Tags: tahajjud

Will my Tahajud prayer be accepted as I was late? I still performed the prayer in the hopes Allah will forgive me and accept my prayer.

Answer (score 1):

It's not counted as tahajjud , because you  made it after fajr time , as far as i understood

just counted as extra nawafil, tough tahajjud is a nawafill but

But if you intended to wake up for tahajjud & tried & didn't wake up then you have the reward probably as tough you did it.  I Think

You can pray tahjjud today & tommorow too. It's not a 1 time chance